# 3 column fluid layout with expanding middle div based on panel positions

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, css-transforms

Apologies for the not-super-descriptive title, I'm having a hard time verbalizing the problem, so let me try again in more detail.

I am using flexbox to create a 3 column layout, where I'm looking to have the middle column expand when either (or both) of the left / right columns (menu panels) are collapsed.

Here's a screen shot of the problem I'm experiencing.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d9mcg7q71hwogog/example.jpg?dl=0

When the panels are open (expanded) all three columns fill the width of the screen. This is good. However, when either of the two sidepanels is animated (collapsed), the center column does not expand to fill in the additional space. This is not good.

I'm not sure if it has to do with the fact that I'm using translateX to toggle the left / right panels and this is a just a theory, but perhaps the center column doesn't realize that the left / right columns have shifted position, so it doesn't know there's more space to fill?

Code to follow:

CSS:

```
<style>
    body {
        background-color: lightslategrey;
    }
    .red {
        background-color: lightcoral;
    }

    .green {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }

    .grey {
        background-color: lightslategray;
    }

    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .ls-toggle, .rs-toggle {
        //position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }

    #left-sidebar, #right-sidebar {
        width: 250px;
        height: 100vh;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }

    #left-sidebar.is-closed {
        transform: translateX(-80%);
    }

    #right-sidebar.is-closed {
        transform: translateX(80%);
    }

    .ls-top, .rs-top {
        display: flex;
        width:100%;
        height:35px;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        background-color: lightslategrey;
    }

    .rs-top {
        justify-content: flex-start;
    }

    #mw-content {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
    }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="d-flex">
    <div id="left-sidebar" class="col- red">
        <div class='ls-top grey'>
            <button class="ls-toggle"><i class="fas fa-angle-left fa-2x"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="mw-content" class="col green">
        <h3> Main Window Content.</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="right-sidebar" class="col- red">
        <div class='rs-top grey'>
            <button class="rs-toggle"><i class="fas fa-angle-right fa-2x"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var lsToggleBtn = document.querySelector('.ls-toggle');
        var lsSidebar = document.querySelector('#left-sidebar');
        var rsToggleBtn = document.querySelector('.rs-toggle');
        var rsSidebar = document.querySelector('#right-sidebar');

        lsToggleBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            lsToggleBtn.classList.toggle('is-closed');
            lsSidebar.classList.toggle('is-closed');
        });

        rsToggleBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            rsToggleBtn.classList.toggle('is-closed');
            rsSidebar.classList.toggle('is-closed');
        });
    });
```

**Things I've tried:**

- Adding flex: 1 1 auto to main content container (mw-content).
- Adding flex: 0 to l/r sidebar containers & flex: 1 1 auto to main content container
- Setting width to 100% on main content container
- Attempting to use translateX on main content container & setting new width when clicking left sidebar

Obviously none of those ideas worked, and I freely admit I'm not the greatest with flexbox, so I'm sure I'm just missing something basic, but I'd appreciate any suggestions you fine folks might have. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to play with "position: absolute" and add two more classList.toggle functions

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var mwContent = document.querySelector('#mw-content');          // !!
  var lsToggleBtn = document.querySelector('.ls-toggle');
  var lsSidebar = document.querySelector('#left-sidebar');
  var rsToggleBtn = document.querySelector('.rs-toggle');
  var rsSidebar = document.querySelector('#right-sidebar');

  lsToggleBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    lsToggleBtn.classList.toggle('is-closed');
    lsSidebar.classList.toggle('is-closed');
    mwContent.classList.toggle('ls-pos');         // here
  });

  rsToggleBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    rsToggleBtn.classList.toggle('is-closed');
    rsSidebar.classList.toggle('is-closed');
    mwContent.classList.toggle('rs-pos');         // here
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightslategrey;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.red {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.green {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.grey {
  background-color: lightslategray;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.ls-toggle,
.rs-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#left-sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#right-sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#left-sidebar.is-closed {
  transform: translateX(-80%);
}

#right-sidebar.is-closed {
  transform: translateX(80%);
}

.ls-top,
.rs-top {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: lightslategrey;
}

.rs-top {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

#mw-content {
  position: absolute;
  right: 250px;
  left: 250px;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.ls-pos {
  left: 50px !important;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.rs-pos {
  right: 50px !important;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <div class="d-flex">
    <div id="left-sidebar" class="col red">
      <div class='ls-top grey'>
        <button class="ls-toggle"><i class="fas fa-angle-left fa-2x"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="mw-content" class="col green">
      <h3> Main Window Content.</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="right-sidebar" class="col red">
      <div class='rs-top grey'>
        <button class="rs-toggle"><i class="fas fa-angle-right fa-2x"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Awesome, that was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks MB! That definitely helps me figure out / learn something new today. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can achieve this using vanilla javascript.

Two functions, one to track the collapsing of section elements and resize the middle section. It checks click and adds the elements (sections) id to an array, a conditional checks the array and if the array `includes` the two outer sections id, we resize the middle section using `style.transform` => `scale()`. The second function resets the collapsible elements.

***More info found in code snippit.***

```js
let clicked = [];
const middle = document.querySelector('#sect2')

let section = document.querySelectorAll('.sect')
let reset = document.querySelector('#reset')

// function 
const resizeOnCollapse = (els) => {
  // loop over the three sections
  els.forEach(sect => {
    // do not allow the middle section to be collapsed
    if (sect.id !== 'sect2') {
      // eventlistener to check a click on the outer sections
      sect.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        // push the clicked elements into an array 
        clicked.push(e.target.id)
        // set the event targets width to 0 
        // essentially collapsing it from view
        e.target.style.width = '0px';
        // conditional that checks if the array 
        // includes the two outer sections
        if (clicked.includes('sect1') && clicked.includes('sect3')) {
          // resize the middle section using
          // transform: scale()
          middle.style.transform = 'scale(1.2)'
          // transition animation on the transform 
          middle.style.transition = 'transform .5s ease-out'
        }
      })
    }
  })
}


// function to reset the elements and reset the array
const resetEls = (el, section) => {
  // eventlistener on click 
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // reset the array
    clicked = [];
    // loop over the sections
    section.forEach((sect) => {
      // reset the width essentially uncollapsing the sections 
      sect.style.width = '30vw';
      // reset the middle transform rule, scale() to 1
      sect.style.transform = 'scale(1)';
    })
  })
}

// call the functions
resetEls(reset, section)
resizeOnCollapse(section)
```

```css
#main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.sect {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 80vh;
}

#sect1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#sect2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#sect3 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button id="reset">reset</button>
<div id="main">
  <div id="sect1" class="sect">
  </div>
  <div id="sect2" class="sect">
  </div>
  <div id="sect3" class="sect">
  </div>
</div>
```